# Why can I place a case inside another case in a switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Here is an example of a `switch` statement. I don't get why it works this way:

```
int main(){

    int number1 = 100, number2 = 200;

    switch(number1){
        case 100:{
            cout << " outer switch number is: " << number1 << endl;
        case 200:{ // any value other than 100
                cout << "inner switch number is: " << number2 << endl;
            }
            break;            
        }
        break;    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

- The program above prints: `100` and then prints the next statement of `case 200`. Also if any value other than `200` is used in the second case, it still gets executed. I know there is no `break` after `case 100`. But why don't I get a compile-time error instead?
- To be clearer, why will any other value inside the inner case also succeed? E.g.,

  ```
  case 70000:
  ```

Comment: A switch/case is pretty much a value calculated goto/label, with some additional constraints.

Comment: there is no `break` statement between `case 100` and `case 200`, therefore the fall through happens.

Comment: [`switch` has much more nasty things than anyone would ever think](http://blog.robertelder.org/switch-statements-statement-expressions/).

Comment: @MárioFeroldi: Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But why don't I get a compile-time error instead?

Because you didn't do anything illegal. A case statement is just a labeled statement. The expression in the switch is evaluated to figure which label to jump to (note the "jump" and "label") and then that statement starts executing. It's just a goto in disguise, to be honest. It's a bit more constrained, but still a jump.

The only constraint, since this is C++, is that you may not skip the initialization of an object by jumping ahead of it.

This feature was famously used in [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) (albeit in C).

> To be more clear, why any other value inside the inner case will also succeed?

Because after the jump is performed, those labels don't matter. They just mark specific statements. After the jump, execution proceeds normally. And normal execution doesn't avoid specific statements just because they are labeled.

Comment: Thanks. But if write `case 0`, or `case 100000` it works for any value??!

Comment: @Alex24 - No it doesn't. For `100` it will start executing the outer block. For `200` it will skip the first instruction in the outer block, and jump into the inner block. If you change `200` to `10000` it will still start executing the outer block because `number1` is `100`.

Comment: I mean if the outer succeeds then whatever the inner value being evaluated will succeed?!!!

Comment: @Alex24 - It's not about success or failure. It's about "go to this line, or this line". But after the lines are figured out, it's still executed **in sequence**. So if you go to line 100, and line 200 is after it, line 200 will be executed afterwards. The only exception is when a `break` is encountered.

Comment: So reasonable! But can you explain a bit what happens when control reaches `case 200`? I only want to know. Thank you.

Comment: You mean the inner case is considered just a label as in assembly?

Comment: @Alex24 - Nothing happens. The label doesn't alter the statement in any way other than allowing the `switch` to jump straight to it. After the jump, it's just a regular old statement.

Comment: @Alex24 - Yes. Exactly like assembly labels. It's just a distinguished statement that can be named.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't see any compilation error? It's because you used the `switch` expression correctly. But, you might not see the results as you want.
First let's try a simple `switch` expression:

```
switch(number1){
    case 100:
        cout<<"the number is 100"<<endl;
        break;
    case 200:
        cout<<"the number is 200"<<endl;
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"the number is neither 100 nor 200"<<endl;
        break;
}
```

If you want to use other numbers, you can add to the `switch-case` block.
If you don't use a break that means the next case is the target. Till you don't use the break the program will continue. The `default` says if non of the above happens I want to do this part.

Let's go to your program and what is going on:

```
switch(number1){
    case 100:{//if the number is 100 it will start from here
        cout << " outer switch number is: " << number1 << endl;
        //it will break after the first break expresion
    case 200:{ // any value other than 100// if the number is 200 it will start from here
            cout << "inner switch number is: " << number2 << endl;
        }
        break; // I meant her is the first break    
    }
    break;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `switch` statement works like `if` statement but it is preferred to it when dealing with more than 2 or 3 choices.

`switch` evaluates conditions in `case` statements. So whenever it finds a case it consider it a condition so it continue executes until a break found as a sign of end of the statement. In your case `case 100` begins but another case is inside so as long as there's no break for 100 ye, everything after it is executed.

```
case 100:
    // do some stuff 
    case 0:
       // do another stuff
    case 5779:
       // do ....
 break;
```

Al the above statements will be executed if only and if `case 100` succeeds.

Remember in C++ you can write:

```
void foo(){
    cout << "foo" << endl:
}

int main(){

    b:
        foo();        

    return 0;
}
```

It like that `label` but only with the keyword `case`. you can say a `case` inside case without its `switch` or preceded by a `break` will work the same way a `label` works.